# Why doesn't my website icon show?

Tags: html, amazon-ec2, icons, favicon

I'm trying to have an icon for my website, I've uploaded my image to [Favic-o Matic's Website](http://www.favicomatic.com) and got the image and the HTML code back, and implemented it. But I can't see my icon anywhere, I've tried deleting the cache and saving my site as a bookmark.  No matter what I do, I can't see my icon, why don't I see it?

---

Some extra nerdy stuff (if helpful): I'm using Amazon AWS EC2 instance, and uploading my files via SSH using Terminal.

---

Here's two screen shots, the first is of my Finder folder that houses my website files on my computer.
**Note: my website is live on my EC2 instance, FYI.**
[image: Finder window]
The second one, this is a screen shot of Terminal accessing the files on my server, the files are at `/var/www/html` as you can see with the `cd` command.

[image]

---

**Update:**
All the image files appear to be there, this is at `/var/www/html`, that is where amazon says to put the files.

### [image]

Here's my icon code, it's placed in the `<head>` element.

```html
<!-- Icon code -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/icons/favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
<meta name="application-name" content="&nbsp;"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/icons/mstile-144x144.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/icons/mstile-70x70.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/icons/mstile-150x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/icons/mstile-310x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/icons/mstile-310x310.png" />
<!-- End Icon code -->
```

Thanks for your time and help!

**My website is at IP [54.213.219.247](http://54.213.219.247)**

Comment: says your site contains malware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Favicons don't work local (your website must be hosted in a server). If it is already online, the problem is probably a wrong path to the files (test it writing the complete path on the url bar example yourwebsite.com/icons/favicon-128.png).

Comment: I edited my post to be clearer than it was, but my website is on my EC2 server, and I don't have a domain yet, my site is at IP 54.213.219.247, why wouldn't the relative path work?  Thanks for the efforts!

Comment: or your favicon files arent there yet, or you wrote the wrong path.

Comment: Understand now! Just did that as well and the same result for me too.  why wouldn't the image be there?

Comment: When I use terminal to see what files are on the server they all appear to be there.

Comment: for the favicon files example: "favicon-16x16.png"

Comment: all the file appear that they are in place.

Comment: If you try http://54.213.219.247/icons/ there is a page there, but certainly not the one I was expecting!

Comment: Maybe you're right, if I try http://54.213.219.247/pictures/down_arrow.png, which I have uploaded a arrow file to, I see the file.

Comment: take a look, your favicons arent here: http://54.213.219.247/icons/ seems like it already had a 'icons' folder full of icons (not yours). So you can try to create a different folder for the icons, example "favicons" or "jefficons".

Comment: if I change the `icons` file to `website_icons` it works, apparently I can't use `icons` as a folder name. http://54.213.219.247/website_icons/favicon-128.png

Comment: FIXED!!!!!! I guess I couldn't use `icons` as a folder name, once changed to `website_icons` and my html edited to reference those files, it WORKED!!!  Now I have a website with an icon, thanks @freestock.tk !

Comment: Great! If you check  [54.213.219.247/icons](http://54.213.219.247/icons/) theres a bunch of system icons; seems to be a protected folder.

Comment: Already figured that out! Did you read my comments? It's fixed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: :) youre welcome; ps: jeffarries.tk is avaible for a free domain at [dot.tk](http://www.dot.tk/)

Comment: dot.tk says jeffarries.tk is taken, but I don't need a dot.tk extension, thanks for the thought!

Comment: maybe it says that its taken because i was checking it here; anyways, see ya;